# Error running app on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I get this strange message error when trying to run an app using `dev_appserver.py`:

```
ERROR    2011-04-21 23:03:44,984 dev_appserver_main.py:407] Fatal error when loading
application configuration:
Value 'warmup' for key ??? does not match expression '^(mail|xmpp_message|rest|startup)$'
in "stackprinter/app.yaml", line 53, column 1
```

I have no idea what may be causing this, I hope someone is able to at least guide me in the right direction!

EDIT: Content of the app.yaml:

```
application: foo
version: 1b
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- datastore_admin: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /test.*
  login: admin  
  script: gaeunit.py
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: app/static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: app/static/images/favicon.ico
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: app/static/docs/robots.txt
  upload: app/static/docs/robots.txt
- url: /crossdomain.xml
  static_files: app/static/docs/crossdomain.xml
  upload: app/static/docs/crossdomain.xml
- url: /sitemap.xml
  static_files: app/static/docs/sitemap.xml
  upload: app/static/docs/sitemap.xml
- url: /javascripts
  static_dir: app/static/javascripts
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: app/static/stylesheets
- url: /images
  static_dir: app/static/images
- url: /docs
  static_dir: app/static/docs  
- url: /deleted
  static_dir: app/static/deleted 
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/deferred/handler.py
  login: admin
- url: /_ereporter
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/report_generator.py
  login: admin
- url: /admin.*
  script: application.py
  login: admin 
- url: /_ah/warmup
  script: application.py
  login: admin 
- url: /.*
  script: application.py
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the contents of your app.yaml?

Comment: Including your `app.yaml` would probably be a good idea, since the error message refers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was that i had an old GAE SDK, Warmup requests were added in the 1.4.0 version.

Cheers